# Question on simplicial complex structure on simple spaces

Tags: general-topology

Consider say $I=[0,1],I'=[0,1)$,$\mathbb{S}^1$, or $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to understand simplicial complex structures on these spaces. In our class text, it is stated that these spaces (among others) admit **a** simplicial complex structure and the barycentric metric relative to the simplicial structure induces the natural euclidean topology on these spaces.

So my question is: Why do these spaces admit a simplicial complex structure such that the barycentric metric wrt to these topologies induce the euclidean topology?

Is this part of a more general situation?

Comment: You should be explicit regarding **which** simplicial structure you are asking about, because **the** simplicial complex on a space is never defined. There is never a unique simplicial complex structure on a topological space $X$ (except when the underlying topological space is discrete). Without knowing which one you are asking about, we cannot know which barycentric metric you are asking about, and so we cannot answer your question.

Comment: Also, your title is quite deceptive; presumably you meant to write *Question on simplicial complex structure on simple spaces*.

Comment: @LeeMosher I edited. I meant to say that these spaces admit a simplicial complex structure such that the barcyentric metric wrt that simplicial complex structure induces the euclidean topology. Is this in general true for spaces, say, such as I=[0,1], I'=[0,1) , $\mathbb{S}^1$, $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @LeeMosher I guess of $I'=[0,1)$ this would just be coming from $I$ and for $\mathbb{S}^1$, it would come from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, which comes from $\mathbb{R}$